# Error on deleting postgres role

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to delete a psql role, reassigning linked object to postgres role beforehand.
But I still get the error message `removal of role "xxx" failed: ERROR:  role "xxx" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`

`DETAIL:  owner of database xxx_db`

Below is the process I use to delete a role (executed by a script):

`su postgres -c "psql xxx_db -c \"REASSIGN OWNED BY xxx TO postgres\"" 2>&1` - OK

`su postgres -c "dropuser tasip" 2>&1`  - this line throw the error when executed.

But if execute this line aside the script, i will get the role `tasip` deleted.
Is there anything I am missing in this process ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Cheers

Comment: Postgres version? The behavior or `REASSIGN OWNED` with regard to database owning depends on it.

Comment: sorry for late reply, the version is 9.1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out the solution.

It wasn't the good syntax for reassignation, the proper one is :

```
ALTER DATABASE adatabase OWNER TO postgres
```

Then it becomes possible to drop the user owning 'adatabase' before reassignation to postgres.